# Spring MVC AccessDeniedHandler multiple tries

Tags: java, spring-mvc, access-denied

I want to give incoming user a change to try at least couple of time before sending him to *"denypage"*. By default in Spring MVC if user has wrong permissions and try to access *"/admin"* resource, Spring mvc redirects user to *"denypage"* like *403* default one. What I want to allow using some attempts to try before sending him to this page. I have tried the next code:

```
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 2;
    private int counter = 0;
    private String errorPage;

    public MyAccessDeniedHandler() {}

    public MyAccessDeniedHandler(String errorPage) {
        this.errorPage = errorPage;
    }

    public String getErrorPage() {
        return errorPage;
    }

    public void setErrorPage(String errorPage) {
        this.errorPage = errorPage;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                          AccessDeniedException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        counter =+ 1;

        if(counter < MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION", exception);
            response.sendRedirect("fail2login");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(errorPage);
        }
    }
}
```

But this code redirects request to *"fail2login"* and when I try another attempt, I am redirected to default URL, not to initial one ("/admin" for example)((
Any propositions?